# Google Sheets - Use "?" to found the symbol in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to count the number of cells that contain the symbol "?" in a specific range.

But the formula `=COUNTIF(C3:C60; "?")` seems to interpret the char as 'any string with one char'.

I tried with `"\?"`, `"'?"` and `"'?'"`.

I tried this solution too : `=SUM(IF(A2:A10="?"; 1; 0))`

Is there an other solution to escape the char and just take it as it is ?

Answer (score 2):

The wildcard escape character for COUNTIF as per the function [help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en-GB) is a tilde:

```
=COUNTIF(C3:C60;"~?")
```

Comment: That's clearly the best and cleanest solution. I'm sad that I didn't see it in the documention. Than you!

Answer (score 1):

try regex it:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(C3:C60; "\?"))
```